# How do i display the name base on the value of the text file with C#?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a text file containing the following data:

- Jason,155
- Peter,200
- May,320
- Jack,100

The above Texts are all in the same `txt` file.

I need to insert the name and the value of the person with the highest value into a separate textbox. I can't figure out how to read the highest value using `StreamReader`.

EDIT: This is the code that i used to read the `txt` file. But I'm not sure how to write the codes to pick the person with the highest value to display in a TextBox.

```
string[] Contestants = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
foreach (var member in Contestants)
{
    string[] first = member.Split(',');
    string firstTemp = first[0] + "," + first[1];
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code ?

Comment: Do you need to insert highest value into a separate textbox or textFile?

Comment: @AnGG I have added my code to read the txt file. But i'm unsure of how to write the code to pick the person with the highest value.

Comment: @Sh.Imran I need to insert highest value into a seperate textbox

Comment: @Zack see my answer, its based on Linq query, in the end name and number will have the details of the person with the maximum number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way is reading each line and filter it using Linq

```
var maxRow = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Where(words => words.Length == 2)
    .Aggregate((i1, i2) => int.Parse(i1[1]) >= int.Parse(i2[1]) ? i1 : i2);

string name = maxRow[0];
int number = int.Parse(maxRow[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I learnt something new today.

Answer (score -2):

would it help, read line by line with streamreader, split  by "," and parse the integer from string?

Read like this

```
using var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
using var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8); 
string line = String.Empty; 
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) { Console.WriteLine(line); }
```

Best Regards

Comment: this is not answer , please add it in comment section

Comment: Shure? I trink you wrong. I can't comment under 50 reputation, so it must be wrong.

Comment: dear @RoXTar, according to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63399478/revisions your post has been edited, my comment return back to your  previous answer.

Comment: Its cause of writing with smartphone. Its a mess, so i must edit. You downvoted to fast